# Why can't nodejs be found?

Tags: linux, node.js, ssh

I'm trying to install some software on my server via SSH, but for some reason node.js can't be found. I type:

```
    './public_html/server/Start-linux.sh'
```

Into the command line which references an install script file, whose code is:

```
 #!/bin/bash

##Function Definition
pause() {
read -p "Press [Enter] key to exit"
}


cd $(dirname $0) # cd scr dir
if [ ! "$(id -u)" = 0 ] && [ ! -f ".readwarning" ]; then
    echo "WARNING: Ogar uses priveleged ports by default, which may" \
        "cause an error. Please either change the ports in the config" \
        "file (gameserver.ini) to two different ports above 1024, or run" \
        "this script as root. This warning will only be shown once, unless" \
        "the file \".readwarning\" is deleted" 1>&2
    touch .readwarning
    sleep 5
fi

#Check which command to execute, nodejs (debian based) or node (others)
#This will give priority to nodejs
command -v nodejs &>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
nodejs index.js
else
command -v nodejs &>/dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    node index.js
else
     nodejs index.js echo "Couldn't find nodejs. Please install it and ensure       it is in your \$PATH"
fi
fi

# Pause
#pause
```

I then get an error message:"Couldn't find nodejs. Please install it and ensure it is in your $PATH".

When I type 'node -v' in the command line it returns 'v4.4.2', so clearly it's there. Why the heck is it saying it's not found? Also what is $PATH? How do I ensure nodejs is in my $path?

I'm a beginner with SSH and node.js so any help would be appreciated. I'm in a linux centos 64bit system.

Answer (score 0):

`nodejs` is the name of the Node.js binary on some systems to avoid conflict with the older program called node `node` for [amateur packet radio networks](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/node) that's part of Ubuntu. They really should rename that package and avoid all the confusion.

The preferred name is `node` and calling `nodejs` is platform specific. I think you could rename those calls to `node` instead and it'd work.

Comment: Or you could make a symlink so that `node` points to `nodejs`, which is what installing the `nodejs-legacy` package via `apt` will do for you in Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: @mscdex That's true, but in this case we're talking about the reverse where `nodejs` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You checked for `nodejs` twice: `command -v nodejs &>/dev/null`

Your second check should be `command -v node &>/dev/null`